# Hyperledger Fabric: Where to find a production quality sample?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we are wondering where can we find a production quality sample for HL Fabric? we have studied the [samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) included with official release and have found that:

- the [balance-transfer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/balance-transfer) sample shows how to write a HL Fabric app and make transactions and queries on the chaincode but uses the cryptogen tool which is not recommended for use in production
- The [fabric-ca](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/fabric-ca) app on the other hand shows how to spin up a network without using cryptogen but does not show how to write an app that can then be used to do transactions, make queries, enroll new users and so on

So we are looking for a sample that combines the best of above two apps. Does such a sample exist? Writing an app to get the benefits of both turned out to be harder than we thought e.g., fabric-ca sample does not output any [network-config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/release-1.3/balance-transfer/typescript/lib/network-config.json) which is needed by balance-transfer and we are facing difficulty figuring out what the network-config should look like in this case. Also we see conflicting code between node and typescript in balance-transfer (although both are javascript) etc.

Answer (score -1):

In the latest master of Hyperledger Fabric, there is a new and much more detailed sample--[the commercial paper](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/commercial_paper.html). 
The tutorial covers the whole lifecycle of a chaincode.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - we were not aware of it. However, it doesn't asnwer our question. The commercial paper uses the basic-network and the basic-network uses cryptogen pre-generated certificates and key material. We want a sample that does not use cryptogen and shows how to build a node app that can perform actions on the network - enroll new users, query chaincode, perform transactions.

Comment: In the commercial paper tutorial, register admin and user scripts are using fabric-ca server to generate the certificates.